# Special Character and html tag parsing in xml

Tags: java, xml, parsing, character

I have an xml in which it contails `<br/>` tag in the element data fiels. I am able to parse it using string builder in Sax parser. Now i want to trim down some of the tags and return back an xml response. In the response xml source i am getting the tag replaces as `&lt;br/>`. My concern is that the "<" gets replaced by `&lt;` but the ">" tag does not get replaced by `&gt;`. Anybody has idea of how to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should escape for XML.
Try [EscapeUtils from Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#StringEscapeUtils%28%29).

Mind that also Java may be having trouble dealing with it.

I prefer first to escapeJava and after that escapeXML.

Usage:

```
    String escapedStr= StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(yourString);
    escapedStr= StringEscapeUtils.escapeXML(yourString);
```

[Apache Commons Lang download link.](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi)